# Could not find RubyGem bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bundler

I've cloned diaspora for github, git://github.com/diaspora/diaspora.git

I tried to install it. An error generated when I use bundle install.

```
$ bundle install 
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:812:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:223:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1146:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:18
```

I'm using rails 3 and ruby 1.8 on ubuntu 11.04. How to fix it? Please help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you install `bundler` gem?

```
$ gem install bundler
```

You might need sudo privileges.

Comment: perhaps, I you're using ruby from ubuntu repos, you may have issues. use RVM instead.

Comment: I've done this, but I still get this error. `Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/panzi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Could not find rubygems-bundler (>= 0) amongst [...] (Gem::LoadError)`

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, maybe you've got the bundle command and bundler gem installed for /usr/bin/ruby, and after that installed another Ruby in /usr/local/bin/ruby?

Could you do a `which ruby` and `head -1 /usr/bin/bundle`? Maybe also a `gem list`?

Comment: `$ which ruby` =>
`/usr/bin/ruby`

`$ head -1 /usr/bin/bundle` =>
`#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8`

Answer (score 2):

Presumably this has been fixed long ago, but for the benefit of others....

My issues was that while I had installed the bundler gem it had been installed in a different location to the current GEM_PATH - so it couldn't be found.

So,

```
GEM_PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ bundle install
```

did the business, setting the value of GEM_PATH to the actual location of the gems folder where the bundler gem has been installed.